# How can I pass an ID name into jQuery as a parameter?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, function, onclick

I have the following code which toggles the visibility of an item with a certain ID:

```
<div onClick="toggleViz()">Click this</div>

<div id="item1" style="display: none;">
   <p>Item 1       
</div>

<div id="item2" style="display: none;">
   <p>Item 2       
</div>

<script>
function toggleViz() {
    var x = document.getElementById("item1");
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I'd like to pass the ID name of the item whose visibility I want to toggle to the function as a parameter, so I don't have to write a new function for every item.

When I try this:

```
<div onClick="toggleViz(item1)">Click this 1</div>
<div onClick="toggleViz(item2)">Click this 2</div>


<div id="item1" style="display: none;">
   <p>Item 1       
</div>

<div id="item2" style="display: none;">
   <p>Item 2       
</div>

<script>
function toggleViz(id_name) {
    var x = document.getElementById(id_name);
    if (x.style.display === "none") {
        x.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        x.style.display = "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I get: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'style')`

Answer (score 0):

So when you pass item1 to your function like that, it doesn't pass it as a string, it'll already passes the element with the id item1. If you wanted to pass it as a string, you would need to do something like this:

```
<div onClick="toggleViz('item1')">Click this 1</div>
```

That way you explicitly pass it as a string and can use it as a string in your function. The way you did, you already get the element in the function, so you could modify it to something like this:

```
function toggleViz(elem) {
    if (elem.style.display === "none") {
        elem.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        elem.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```